# Android - Pass data from parent fragment to child fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my application I want to pass an search query from an edittext to my adapter which is located in one of the child fragment. In the childfragment I want to filter the adapter based on the text I have entered in the edittext which is located in the parent fragment.

Firstly I try get a fragment from the viewpageradapter and then call the global variable of the adapter(which is public) which results in an null pointer on the adapter.

```
Edittext searchFilter = new Edittext(getActivity())
final FragmentShows fragment = (FragmentShows) adapter.getItem(1);
searchFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if(fragment != null) {
--> NULL POINTER  fragment.adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
        }}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});
```

Next I've tried (don't really understand interfaces) to make an interface and let the child fragment implements this interface:

Parent fragment

```
private Fragmentfilter filter
...
Edittext searchFilter = new Edittext(getActivity())
final FragmentShows fragment = (FragmentShows) adapter.getItem(1);
searchFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    --> NULL POINTER HERE filter.OnTextChangedListener(charSequence.toString());
     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});
```

Childfragment:

```
public class FragmentShows extends Fragment implements FragmentFilter{
    ...
    @Override
    public void OnTextChangedListener(String searchQuery) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(searchQuery);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface FragmentFilter {

    void OnTextChangedListener(String searchQuery);

}
```

Can someone explain why it's not working, and maybe help me/push me in the right direction on how to solve this problem.

I doesn't have to give a result back just the adapter being filtered on the entered query.

Comment: For the second case you don't set the value of `filter` to `fragment`...

Comment: @AnubianNoob where do I have to do that?

Comment: It depends on the way you are adding the child fragment. If it's directly on you fragment layout (fragment tag on you XML), then you need to use the FragmentManager to recover the reference to the child fragment. If you are adding the child fragment with a transaction, just keep the reference to that fragment and assign it to your FragmentFilter variable

Comment: @JorgeMendez so I have to do something like `filter = fragment`? Could you give me an example on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value to the variable `filter` is not assigned and that's why the NullPointerException is happening. So you need to keep the reference to your child fragment depending on the way you're attaching it. There are 2 options:

1) If you're attaching your child fragment directly to your fragment layout (with the `fragment` tag on your xml), then you need to recover the instance and assign it this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
Fragment childFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.child_fragment);
filter = (FilterFragment) childFragment;
```

Where `R.id.child_fragment` is the id you set to your fragment on your XML, and the XML might look like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        class="com.path.to.your.fragment.ChildFragment"
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

2) The second case is if you're attaching your child fragment using a transaction like add or replace, then you just need to keep the reference to the child fragment's instance and assign it to `filter` variable. It might look like this:

```
Fragment childFragment = new ChildFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, childFragment).commit();
filter = (FilterFragment) childFragment;
```

Where R.id.fragment_container, is the viewgroup where you're attempting to attach your child fragment. And your layout XML might look like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```